# Solve system of quadratic equations faster than SymPy

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

N = 13
c = np.loadtxt('matrix_c.txt')
c = sp.Matrix(c)
p = sp.symbols(f'p1:{N*N+1}')
p = sp.Matrix(p)
E = sp.symbols('E')
E = sp.Matrix([E])
R = sp.symbols('R')
R = sp.Matrix([R])
g = np.loadtxt('gradient.txt')
g = sp.Matrix(g)
B = np.loadtxt('hessian.txt')
B = sp.Matrix(B)

q = E + g.T @ p + 0.5 * p.T @ B @ p
constraint = (p.T - c.T) @ (p - c) - R **2

# Method of Lagrange multipliers
lamda = sp.symbols('lambda')
L = q - 0.5 * lamda * constraint

gradL = [sp.diff(L, var) for var in p]
eqs = gradL + [constraint]

sol = sp.solve(eqs, [*p[0:N*N], lamda], dict=True)
```

On the last line, `sol`, it takes a lot of time to solve lambda. Is there another way to optimize this code, using or not using SymPy?

Comment: The code doesn't work because it loads a file "matrix_c.txt".

Comment: How much time?  That's a non-trivial problem.

Comment: It worked @OscarBenjamin, I had omitted a line (c = sp.Matrix(c)), but I already corrected it.

Comment: The code does not run if anyone else runs it because it loads files that do not exist except on your computer. http://sscce.org/